# How can I bound type variable to integer in scipy minimization?

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

I use from scipy for minimization.
Variable must to be 0 or 1.
How can I do this?

Comment: It's not supported (and the question is too broad to recommend alternatives).

Answer (score -2):

I find the solution with add the constraint.

```
cons = ({'type':'eq'
          ,'fun': lambda x_f : np.array([(x_f[:x_ini_size][i]-int(x_f[:x_ini_size][i]))
                                    for i in sentences_idx])})
```